# How do I setup an Endpoint URL with a Path Parameter within API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to setup an API Gateway in front of my existing setup. Whenever I try to add an endpoint with a parameter, I get an error.

```
Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression parameter specified: method.request.querystring.type]
```

Here are screenshots:

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

In order to create a **Path Parameter** (which is a different concept than a *query string*) you create a resource with brackets, like in `{your-parameter-name}`.

➡️ **Path Paremeter: `http://example.com/products/{id}/...`**

A query string appends to the end of the URL like in `?value=123`

The console actually gives a description tip on how to do it:

> You can add path parameters using brackets. For example, the resource path {username} represents a path parameter called 'username'. Configuring /{proxy+} as a proxy resource catches all requests to its sub-resources.

Here's how to do it:

1. Create a resource called `/products`

[image]

2. Now create a child resource with a path text like `{product}`. This is the path parameter.

[image]

3. Finally, add a method in which the Endpoint URL field will map the resource parameter to the target URL, which in my example is `https://dummyjson.com/products/{product}`. The console will help you with the suggestions and validation.

[image]

That's it. You can now test your API method in the console and see that everything is routed to the target endpoint, including the path parameter.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem too.
This is what you need to do:

BTW: `/number` **is not a part of this example**

1. Create new API resource.
2. Go to `Method Request` on the `Method Execution` page

[image]

3. Add your params under `URL Query String Parameters`. You can set some params to be `Required` as well.

[image]

4. Return to the `Method Execution` screen (see image num 1) and now click on `Integration Request`
5. Now you can see/set (in my case it was created automatically) your params under URL `Query String Parameters`. If not, you can define them as you see in the picture.
6. After you finish all, click on `Actions` and `Deploy API`.
   You can get your `Invoke URL` under the `Stages` tab on the left menu.

[image]

For more information, you can see [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-mappings.html#getting-started-mappings-set-methods) (AWS docs) it has good explanation about this process.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: does it add query param or path params ?

Comment: this is query param, not path param, they are different things.

Comment: @GholamrezaEghbali yep, I've added an answer that matches what the question is asking